# Android: post data from custom thread to different (fragment) layouts in tabbed activity

Tags: android, multithreading, queue, handler, message

I need some help with my little android project.
So, i have to collect data in a thread. I've created a thread and handler to send message to the ui thread. Which works in a simple activity. 
But here comes the problem: I want to display the data in different ways: "real time data" = in a textview, data in a chart, and previous (historycal data). 
So for this, i created a tabbed activity with 3 fragments (one for real time data, one for a chart, one for the historycal chart). But all of these fragments needs the same data from my thread (except the last fragment which needs the last 5-10 i donw know how many data).
So where shall i start to read? What options i have? Shall i use the same handlers in these fragments? If yes how can i reference them? Or i have to make  I am a bit confused, please help me.

Here is the "main" tabbed activity (please note that the messages from the thread are dummy data yet) :

```
public class ThermoMeasurementActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private final int SENSOR_POS_BOTTOM = 0x00;
private final int SENSOR_POS_TOP = 0xFF;

private Handler handler;





/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_thermo_measurement);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    handler = new Handler() {

        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            String aResponse = msg.getData().getString("message");

            if ((null != aResponse)) {

                Log.d("mytag", "Temp = " + aResponse);
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("mytag", "Temp = " + aResponse);
            }

        }
    };

    ThermoReaderTask thermoReaderTask = new ThermoReaderTask(handler, SENSOR_POS_BOTTOM, 1000);
    thermoReaderTask.start();
    ThermoReaderTask thermoReaderTask2 = new ThermoReaderTask(handler, SENSOR_POS_TOP, 1000);
    thermoReaderTask2.start();

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_thermo_measurement, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */


/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                ThermoMeter tabThermoMeter = new ThermoMeter();
                return tabThermoMeter;
            case 1:
                RealTimeThermoChart rtThermoChart = new RealTimeThermoChart();
                return rtThermoChart;
            case 2:
                HistoryChart historyChart = new HistoryChart();
                return historyChart;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Thermo Meter";
            case 1:
                return "Real Time Chart";
            case 2:
                return "History Chart";
        }
        return null;
    }
}



public class ThermoReaderTask extends Thread
{

    private Handler handler;
    int looptime;
    int sensorPos;

    ThermoReaderTask(Handler handler, int sensorPos, int looptime)
    {
        this.handler = handler;
        this.looptime = looptime;
        this.sensorPos = sensorPos;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while(true) {
                String msg = "error";
                if(sensorPos == SENSOR_POS_BOTTOM)
                {
                    msg = "BOTTOM TEMP = 28";
                }else if(sensorPos == SENSOR_POS_TOP)
                {
                    msg = "TOP TEMP = 28";
                }
                Message msgObj = handler.obtainMessage();
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("message", msg);

                msgObj.setData(b);
                handler.sendMessage(msgObj);

                sleep(looptime);
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {

        }
    }

}
}
```

And here is one of the fragments (please not that the commented parts are just attempts):

```
public class ThermoMeter extends Fragment implements 
CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

private int TEMP_MODE_TOP = 0x00;
private int TEMP_MODE_BOTTOM = 0x00;
private final int SENSOR_POS_BOTTOM = 0x00;
private final int SENSOR_POS_TOP = 0xFF;

private ImageView imgvUnitTop;
private ImageView imgvUnitBottom;
private ToggleButton tbTempTop;
private ToggleButton tbTempBottom;
private Handler handler;
private TextView tvTempTop;
private TextView tvTempBottom;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1thermometer, container, false);

    imgvUnitTop = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imgvTop);
    tbTempTop = (ToggleButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tbTempTop);
    imgvUnitBottom = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imgvBottom);
    tbTempBottom = (ToggleButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tbTempBottom);
    tbTempBottom.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    tbTempTop.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    tvTempTop = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvTempTop);
    tvTempBottom = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvTempBottom);

     /*handler = new Handler() {

        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            String aResponse = msg.getData().getString("message");

            if ((null != aResponse)) {

                Log.d("mytag", "Temp = " + aResponse);
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("mytag", "Temp = " + aResponse);
            }

        }
    };*/


  /*  ThermoReaderTask thermoReaderTask = new ThermoReaderTask(handler, SENSOR_POS_BOTTOM, 1000);
    thermoReaderTask.start();
    ThermoReaderTask thermoReaderTask2 = new ThermoReaderTask(handler, SENSOR_POS_TOP, 1000);
    thermoReaderTask2.start();*/
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (buttonView.getId() == R.id.tbTempTop) {
        if(isChecked)
        {
            TEMP_MODE_TOP = 0x00;
            imgvUnitTop.setImageResource(R.drawable.celsius);
        }else
        {
            TEMP_MODE_TOP = 0xFF;
            imgvUnitTop.setImageResource(R.drawable.fahrenheit);
        }
    }
    else if(buttonView.getId() == R.id.tbTempBottom){
        if(isChecked)
        {
            TEMP_MODE_BOTTOM = 0x00;
            imgvUnitBottom.setImageResource(R.drawable.celsius);
        }else
        {
            TEMP_MODE_BOTTOM = 0xFF;
            imgvUnitBottom.setImageResource(R.drawable.fahrenheit);
        }
    }
}

}
```

Could you please give me some links, tutorials, hints anything?

Comment: Did you try handle the data in your activity and have your activity distribute the data to your fragments? In case your question gets closed later, for being too case specific, you might wanna lookup 'how to communicate between fragment and activity'

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it too, but the fact that i generated the tab activity in studio (which is extended from AppCompat) makes it harder :/

Comment: In Fragment, you can override onAttach() to keep a reference of your activity. Then when needed, call methods from your activity to obtain data. Another way would be, from your activity, use FragmentManager to find the fragment that you want to update, and update it.